# Only allowing WhatsApp traffic through firewalls

Tags: firewalls, whatsapp

Problem:

On our client's ship, we have an expensive backup internet connection. We want the backup connection to only allow WhatsApp traffic. This way we won't be greeted with an extreme bill because someone downloaded some movies.

Our findings:

We have tested this with a Draytek and some Fortinet equipment. With Draytek we came to the point where we could only allow traffic from Facebook servers. This is since WhatsApp, Facebook and Instagram etc are currently all on the same network (probably).

On our Fortinet equipment, we did manage to only allow WhatsApp (they have like a massive database of IP addresses of services) but Fortinet works on a subscription basis and we can't offer some 100$+ subscription for something they will only use once a year maybe.

I had the idea that maybe WhatsApp packets have a unique header. This way we could just allow packets if they have this header and block the rest. The problem is I haven't been able to find anything related to this and as far as I can see only the first connection is recognizable.

Images and photos are also still an issue.

Question:

Does anyone have any knowledge about WhatsApp packet structure?

Comment: Whatsapp traffic is encrypted. You won't be able to read the headers. That's why your filters work on IPs.

Comment: 100$/yr is a problem compared to the potential costs of not filtering? You are going to spend more than 100$ of your own time trying to invent your own solution ... And with a paid filter, it can keep itself updated to changes and allows you to add more than just WhatsApp traffic.

Comment: See [Network Requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/network-requirements/) for the description of what domains and ports are used by WhatsApp (Business). Based on this you might be able to adjust your firewall settings. There is nothing special about the packet structure, i.e. port 443 is HTTPS, port 80 is HTTP and port 5222 is probably XMPP.

Comment: Allow https://v.whatsapp.net:443 domain which is a registeration URL and allow WhatsApp CDN IPs. WhatsApp uses [noise pipes](https://noiseprotocol.org/noise.html#noise-pipes) to encrypt TCP payload so you cannot recognise its FunXMPP protocol traffic. It uses port 5222 for noise pipes channel. Block UDP to prevent VoIP.